# embarrassingly parallel problem in python

Tags: python, concurrency, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have 634 *.npy files, each contain a 2D numpy array of shape (8194, 76). I want to use STL decomposition on each column five time with different frequencies. so what I'm trying to do is:

```
for file in files:
    for column in columns:
        for freq in frequencies:
            res = STL(file[:,column], period = freq)
            decomposed = np.vstack((res.trend, res.seasonal, res.resid)).T
    np.save(decompoesd)
```

finally the shape of decomposed should be (8194,1140). How can I parallize this? as it would take over 2 months to run in serial implementation.

Comment: Any feedback please?

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback @ArtiomKozyrev, It worked perfectly by parallelizing file level, thank you so much for your help.   I made simulate_cpu_bound(file) takes a file process it and write it to a disk. I will try next parallelize the CPU heavy task itself, any hint on how to group the res output from each processor and write it to a disk using single process then only after that, all other processors take the next file and do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


FILES = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]


def simulate_cpu_bound(file):
    2 ** 100000000  # cpu heavy task
    # or just use time.sleep(n), where n - number of seconds
    return file


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(8) as f:
        res = f.map(simulate_cpu_bound, FILES)

    res = list(res)

    print(res)
```

Comment: *multithreading* is definitely not what you want to use for a CPU heavy task unless that task is implemented, for example, as a CPU-language -implemented function that releases the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). Did you try timing calling `simulate_cpu_bound` 8 times in a loop and then timing your multithreading version? You will not see much of a difference. Of course, if you change the function to just the `sleep` version you will because `sleep` is not CPU-intensive and does release the GIL.. There I would expect a time reduction of approximately 8-fold.

Comment: @Booboo My mistake, I even did not pay attention that imported `ThreadPoolExecutor` instead of `ProcessPoolExecutor`, thanks. I made the required changes.